# Multilinear Function Proofs

Tags: linear-algebra

A multilinear function is said to be "alternating" if it follows these two rules:

a) if there is a repeated vector, then the output of the function is zero
b) swapping two input vectors changes the output sign.

How do you prove the the multilinear function :  $f(\vec{v},\vec{w},\vec{v})=0$ given that any vectors of $\vec{v}$,$\vec{w}$ are in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Answer (score 0):

$f(v, w, v) = - f(v, v, w)$.  Now, what happens if you switch the first and second $v$?

Comment: Do you mean the first and second _v_ from the positive function?

Comment: No, I mean the two $v$s on the right-hand side.